# Help me find this "new" musical instrument, maybe invented in the 70s

Tags: instruments

The question was closed by an admin. I didn't find precisely what I was looking for, but I found this really cool instrument called Exquis which allows for what I'm talking about, to make scales easier.

---

I'm sorry I can't be more descriptive, because my memory is super faint, and I don't know anything about music. [image]

In my memory, you set a note somehow, and then the buttons to the left and right play the same note at different octaves.

I'm not sure what terminology is needed here. But I think it was touted as making it impossible to hit a wrong note, or to make it make scales easier.

If anyone knows the name of this instrument please tell me!

Thanks!

Comment: Did it have more than one set of these buttons, so it could play more than one note? (The same note in different octaves is still just one note, it would be more like tuned rhythm than a melodic instrument.) Or are you thinking of alternative note layouts like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicki%E2%80%93Hayden_note_layout#/media/File:Wicki-Hayden_Musical_Note_Layout.png

Comment: @j-g-faustus Thanks for the attempt. I would imagine you could press multiple buttons at the same time. Would it make sense for the buttons to be different by half an octave? That doesn't sound right. I just remember that it was supposed to make scales easier somehow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because instrument identification is off topic

Comment: Kinda looks like Simon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game)

Comment: Looks like a chromatic tuner to me

Answer (score 1):

[image: drumkat]

Could it perhaps be a drumkat?

Comment: There’s another drumkat that doesn’t have the rounded shapes and looks angular like in the question

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but this isn't it. I'm pretty sure the instrument was tonal, not percussive.